# Zend Framework 2.0 Acl Library

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-acl

Ok i already started out this new project for 2 weeks and so far so good.

Up till today i just realize there is no Acl component in Zend 2.0.Is it true? Or im missing something.

So currently im clueless with my application acl.

Did you guys have any suggestion of any acl component that work well with Zend 2.0 that i did not aware of or should i just download Zend 1.x instead.

Any input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACL component in Zend Framework 2.0 is now called `Zend\Permissions\Acl`.

I highly recommend [reviewing the reference manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html).  A simple search for the term on that page brought it up right away.

Comment: Thx u so much, my bad i cant find the refference about acl :/